# Mock third party api call in test

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, retrofit2, integration-testing

I have a project written with java and spring boot.
which I have in the program api call.
For this project, I need to write a test and I want to mock the response of api call.
I use retrofit for third party api call.
My question is, how can I do this?
I should write unit test or integration test? which on is correct? which on is the best practice?

[This is how I make the retrofit.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6GFZ.png)

I used wired mock library but it didn't do what I wanted.

Comment: check this example please : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mock-rest-template